# Hibernate Criteria.list() causing java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm coming back to Java after a few years away and this is my 2nd day looking at hibernate and don't fully understand it yet.

I have the following criteria which is performing a join:

```
Criteria cr = s.createCriteria(Bla.class, "bla");
cr.setFetchMode("bla.nodePair", FetchMode.JOIN);
cr.createAlias("bla.nodePair", "node_pair");
cr.add(Restrictions.in("bla.blaName", (List<Bla>) getBlas()));

ProjectionList columns = Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("node_pair.priNode"))
    .add(Projections.property("bla.blaName"))
    .add(Projections.property("node_pair.secNode"))
    .add(Projections.property("bla.port"));

cr.setProjection(columns);
List<Object[]> list = cr.list(); // Exception occurs here
```

This is creating as far as I can tell a valid SQL query and exactly what i'm after.

However, when I try to generate a list of results `cr.list();` I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.some.package.domainobject.Bla cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How should I construct my List. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Your example seems like it's entirely something you made up for practice.  Is the thing in the database actually of type class `Bla`?  Did you put it there?  You could be trying to read a different object out of the database and that's tripping you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Criteria API, the Exception is always(?) thrown when attempting to get the results.

In your case, the problematic line is probably

```
cr.add(Restrictions.in("bla.blaName", (List<Bla>) getBlas()));
```

You seem to check if a `java.lang.String` is part of a `Collection<Bla>`.

If your `equals` and `hashcode` methods in `Bla` use the `blaName` field, you should be able to use

```
cr.add(Restrictions.in("bla", (List<Bla>) getBlas()));
```

Otherwise, implements a `getBlasNames()` function which returns a `List<String>`

Comment: If I comment out `List<Object[]> list = cr.list();` then no exception is thrown so I don't believe `cr.add(Restrictions.in("bla.blaName", (List<Bla>) getBlas()));` is the issue :/

Comment: No SQL is genereated before you attempt to get the result list. That is what happens when you call `cr.list();`.

Comment: You are quite right. Not sure what you are talking about regarding `equals` and `hashcode` methods? Can you give an example ?

Comment: I just meant that if you consider your `Bla` entities equals if their `blaName` field is, then your `equals` and `hashcode` methods should use that field to compute their result. In this case, you should be able to use `Restrictions.in("bla", (List<Bla>) getBlas())`. usually, entities have an `id` field that is used to check equality. In this latter case, you should build a `List<String>` in a `getBlasNames()` method